# Selection of copper alloy for electrical and wear applications

Tags: electrical-engineering, materials

I am working on a project which involves applying electrical load across a metal contact filled with lubricants (bearing applications). However, I am missing one of the blocks as attached and I cannot figure it out what material this is. Looking at the posts here, I am presuming this must be some copper alloy such as brass, however, I know that the rotating disc that this block sits on is of brass material and that can raise issues such as wear due to the presence of similar materials?

Any suggestions what material I can use for this application to not damage the discs while providing good conductivity?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like phosphor bronze to me which makes sense as it has good bearing properties and reasonable electrical conductivity.

It could also potentially be sintered (ie porous), oil filled bronze bushings are fairly common.

Comment: It seems that phosphor bronze is harder than brass (which I think is used for the disc); does it not mean that the disc will be consumable? I would like the block to act as the consumable - I have attached another picture showing their positions.

Comment: The disk looks like it could be bronze as well, it has that red/brown hue. The block  could  possibly  be a leaded bronze which is a bit softer and is somewhat self-lubricating.